# An error in the sparql query when processing with Python

Tags: python, sparql

I am processing a sparql query with Python.

```
def query(var):
query_with_placeholder="""
SELECT ?same_context as ?context  str(?context_label) as ?context_label ?same_s as ?s str(?s_label) as ?s_label ?s_type ?p "$ENTITY_CODE$" as ?gene  str(?text) as ?text 
WHERE {
?transcript <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/SO_transcribed_from> <http://rdf.ebi.ac.uk/resource/ensembl/$ENTITY_CODE$> .
?transcript <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/SO_translates_to> ?ensembl_protein .
?reflect_protein owl:sameAs ?ensembl_protein
graph ?event {
?s ?p ?reflect_protein .
}.
{
?s a <http://lcsb.uni.lu/biokb#Chemical> .
?s owl:sameAs ?same_s .
?same_s rdfs:label ?s_label .
} UNION {
?s a <http://lcsb.uni.lu/biokb#Protein> .
?s owl:sameAs ?same_s .
?ensembl_transcript <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/SO_translates_to> ?same_s .
?ensembl_transcript rdfs:label ?s_label
}
?s a ?s_type .

?sentence <http://lcsb.uni.lu/biokb#hasEvent> ?event .
?sentence <http://lcsb.uni.lu/biokb#containsEntity> ?context .
?sentence <http://lcsb.uni.lu/biokb#text> ?text .
?context a <http://lcsb.uni.lu/biokb#Tissue> .
?context owl:sameAs ?same_context .
?same_context rdfs:label ?context_label .
}"""

new_query=query_with_placeholder.replace("$ENTITY_CODE$",var)

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://biokb.lcsb.uni.lu/sparql")

sparql.setQuery(new_query)

sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)

result_of_query = sparql.query().convert()

return result_of_query
```

Var is an element from a list I am iterating through. 
As a result of using this function I got a mistake

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: File not found
```

and

```
EndPointNotFound: EndPointNotFound: it was impossible to connect with the endpoint in that address, check if it is correct. 

Response:
b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <title>Error HTTP/1.1 404 File not found</title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <h3>Error HTTP/1.1 404 File not found</h3><pre>\nThe requested URL was not found    URI  = \'/sparql\'\n  </pre></body></html>\n'
```

And thus my query stops iterating at 65th element. But I still can run the query for that elements and further ones so I suppose it must work.

Where is the mistake? And how it could be corrected?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the public SPARQL endpoint will block too many requests in a too short time, to avoid flooding. You could try to add some delay

Comment: The right thing is to add a delay in querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mistake appears when you run the query to DataBase too often during short period of time.

```
EndPointNotFound: EndPointNotFound: it was impossible to connect with the endpoint in that address, check if it is correct. 

Response:
b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <title>Error HTTP/1.1 404 File not found</title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <h3>Error HTTP/1.1 404 File not found</h3><pre>\nThe requested URL was not found    URI  = \'/sparql\'\n  </pre></body></html>\n'
```

**Add to python code the following:**

```
import time
time.sleep(2)
```

Where 2 - time in seconds.